# How can we create class diagrams in Xcode 4.6.1 with the existing code of iPhone app?

Tags: ios

I am using Xcode 4.6.1, I want to create class diagrams from existing code in Xcode please help me with it. I tried with different tools like autograph, Omni Graffle but confused with those.Creating class diagram for documentations in ios.
          Please give me help on how to create class diagram for existing code in iOS with Xcode.

Answer (score 2):

There is no built in functionality in Xcode for creating class diagrams. As you mentioned in your answer, your best option is to use a tool like Omnigraffle.

You can simply drag your Xcode project file onto Omnigraffle's icon and it'll scan your project and create a class diagram for you. You're then free to tweak it and make it look how you like.